# $x + y \equiv x - y \equiv 1, 7 \space mod \space 8$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm stuck on the following problem:

> Let $x, y, z$ be primitive Pythagorean triples with $y$ even
>
> Prove that $x + y \equiv x - y \equiv 1, 7 \space mod \space 8$

So far I've tried forming all possible combinations of values. For example, we know that $x, y$ can only take values $1 - 7$ because they are Pythagorean triples. This approach hasn't worked out that well and I'm in need of some help.

Comment: @Benzne_O: Are you aware that every primitive Pythagorean triple $(x, y, z)$ has the form $x = m^2 - n^2$, $y = 2mn$, $z = m^2 + n^2$ where $m$ and $n$ are coprime integers of different parities, and $m > n$?

Comment: yes, but how does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Michael Albanese's comment we have

$x\pm y = (m\pm n)^2-2n^2$, where $m\pm n$ is odd. Note that $(m\pm n)^2\equiv 1\pmod 8$ and $2n^2\equiv 0\pmod 8$ if $n$ is even or $2n^2\equiv 2\pmod 8$ if $n$ is odd.

The result follows.